# How to set Stripe test mode on both Stripe & Webform-CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm, stripe, testing

I am attempting to test a webform that renews membership.  I have set Stripe dashboard to 'Test mode' but when I submit a test credit card (4242 etc) I get tbe message from Stripe 'Your card was declined. Your request was in live mode, but used a known test card.'.  So how do I make a request in test mode?  I guess something on the Civi side?

Answer (score 4):

On the CiviCRM part of the webform, in the 'Contribution' section there is a field 'Payment Processor Mode' where you can set either 'Test Mode' or 'Live Transactions' (and save this, of course, not forgetting to reset both this and Stripe dashboard when going live).

Answer (score 0):

On the manage contribution pages dont use the bottom right hand links > test-drive as this actually uses the live keys - so any test cards will fail.

Instead go to manage contribution pages > title and settings page then use the contribution links button top left and choose online contribution (test-drive). Just soent 1 1/2 hours trying to debug and online with stripe support

Comment: thx. you might have done better to ask and answer your own question here, since this one seems to be specifically about webform_civicrm where as yours sounds like it relates to pure civi contribution forms

Comment: hmm. actually you may not be able to do above without more points.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - first time commenting on here. Wasnt really a question but more of a tip, I think still relevant to testing?

Comment: Am curious about this advice. I pulled up both links on a site. one is /civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&action=preview&id=1 the other is /civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&action=preview, other than the order I don't believe these are substantially different. perhaps you can add examples to your 'hint' to make this clearer, or am i missing the point?